# Is there a printk-style log parser?

Tags: linux, logging, systemd

The journald of systemd supports kernel-style logging. So, the service can write on stderr the messages starting with "<6>", and they'll be parsed like info, "<4>" - warning.

But while developing the service it's launched outside of systemd. Is there any ready-to-use utilities to convert these numbers into readable colored strings? (it would be nice if that doesn't complicate the gdb workflow)

Don't want to roll my own.

Answer (score 0):

There is no tool to convert the output but a simple sed run would do the magic.

As you said journal would strip off `<x>` token from the beginning of your log message and convert this to log level. What I would do is check for some env. variable in the code. For ex:

```
if (COLOR_OUTPUT_SET)
  printf ("[ WARNING ] - Oh, snap\n");
else
  printf ("<4> Oh, snap\n");
```

Comment: The question is how to integrate sed magic with the gdb magic.

Comment: Then the question has nothing to do with systemd or?

Comment: Maybe systemd has a tool for that, since journald already parsing the input (and since systemd is a horrible all-in-one mess™ :) ). Also, I've mentioned systemd to avoid inevitable suggestions to use a different format.